# Improperly Configured database backend django and mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, backend

I've just cloned a repo and when I try to run my python app I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)   
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
        self.check(display_num_errors=True)   
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
        include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,   
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
        new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 28, in check_all_models
        errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))   
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1172, in check
        errors.extend(cls._check_long_column_names())   
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1587, in _check_long_column_names
        connection = connections[db]   
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 212, in
__getitem__
        backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])   
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 135, in load_backend
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sql_server.pyodbc' isn't an available database backend. Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:

    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3' 
Error was: No module named sql_server.pyodbc.base
```

I'm not sure what I've missed setting this up. I'v checked on mysql and the database exists in there

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| mydb               |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And my settings file looks like this

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'dbuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'dbpassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS' : {
        'sql_mode': 'ANSI',
        "init_command": "SET foreign_key_checks = 0;"},

        },
}
```

??

EDIT:

I had another database as follows

```
'db2': {
        'NAME': 'db2',
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        .......
    },
```

And when I changed this ENGINE to django.db.backends.mysql it seems to work. Seems like I'm just having problems installing this...

Comment: The app might be containing other configs that are trying to connect to other db using the backend mentioned above

Comment: try installing `pip install django-pyodbc` and check it works.

Comment: @PiyushMaurya I get an error 'In file included from src/buffer.cpp:12:
    src/pyodbc.h:56:10: fatal error: 'sql.h' file not found
    #include <sql.h>
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1'

Comment: Can we have the repo to test locally?